# What are the drawbacks when increasing the number of threads

Tags: openmp

The number of logical cores in my machine is 8. What would be the drawbacks if I increase the number of threads to be for example 16 `omp_set_num_threads(16);`?

Answer (score 1):

Cache invalidation is a big one. Let's assume each core will work on two threads. When one thread is swapped out for another all of the cache entries are invalidated, and thus data needs to be loaded from a higher level cache or main memory for the new thread. That's going to slow down processing. There is no guarantee this won't happen if you keep the number of threads at 8, but there is less of a chance (in a multiprocessing environment, any time a new process is moved onto a core this will happen).

Comment: Also, consider that OpenMP runtimes (at least the LLVM one and the one used by Intel compilers [which are actually the same :-)]) have default settings which work well when there is no over-subscription. In particular they leave worker threads spinning for a while in various places (for instance when entering barriers) rather than immediately entering the kernel, since this improves the performance when there is no over-subscription. But once you have over-subscription it's bad! So you need to set KMP_BLOCKTIME=0 if you're going to do this with those compilers!